# Split the date and rows based on the duration

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data with S.no, ID, from date, to date and duration where I want to create separate new rows with the in between dates for each id based on the duration. The input data and the expected output are mentioned in the below picture.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried - where is your current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give you an idea how to go about it with formulas

[image]

Formula in `A7`:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(REPT($A$2:$A$4&" ",$E$2:$E$4))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(CONCAT(REPT($A$2:$A$4&" ",$E$2:$E$4))))),(ROW(A1)-1)*LEN(CONCAT(REPT($A$2:$A$4&" ",$E$2:$E$4)))+1,LEN(CONCAT(REPT($A$2:$A$4&" ",$E$2:$E$4))))*1
```

entered through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Formula in `B7`:

```
=VLOOKUP($A7,$A$2:B$4,COLUMN(),FALSE)
```

Drag till `E7`...

Formula in `F7`:

```
=$C7+COUNTIFS($B$6:B6,$B7,$C$6:C6,$C7)
```

Drag till `G7`...

Drag all formulas down...

While there are **limitations** to the formulas I used, on a large dataset VBA might be prevered.